# Which Statistical Model To Use

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

I work in aviation and we are having a problem with a certain system on a fleet of aircraft. Preliminary research has shown that these problems tend to crop up in the winter time in sporadic intervals, only to disappear or greatly diminish in frequency in the spring and summer.

I suspect that when the temperature is cold and we use deicing fluid to get rid of ice and frost on the aircraft skin, that fluid is penetrating various electrical connectors and wreaking havoc. This is more so than ordinary rain because of the high volume and concentration of the fluid.

I have dates, station location, and weather temps for each departure location. Would a linear regression be sufficient to show a correlation between weather temps and this problem? If not, what sort of modeling could I use to show the validity (or lack thereof) that the weather (and thereby our use of deicing equipment) is influencing the frequency of said problems?

Comment: Sounds more like a classification problem to me where you'd use logistic regression:  you would take your information/data and the classification is 1 if the problem occurred and 0 if it didn't.  Also, you don't seem to need statistics to answer your second paragraph: just perform an experiment by  when the temp is cold, put the fluid on the aircraft skin, and see if it penetrates?

Comment: With hundreds of thousand of flights among these 60 or so aircraft, the majority of the time, the fault would not actually occur. I suppose we could throw in weather, etc... to try and narrow it down, but even then, the occurrences probably only happen once every 20 flights.... Hardly the stuff for trend analysis... Yet, on an airplane that makes 10 or so legs a day, “we” see the occurrence happening every other day or so. This makes the problem look chronic and extremely repetitious if even every 20 legs or so. In some cases, a chronic problem will disappear only to come back 6 months later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is whether two variables are positively correlated but you have no theoretical expectation as to the graph's shape (linear, quadratic etc.), I recommend rank correlation. If on the other hand you need to be able to make quantitative predictions, you may wish to add a line/curve of best for in Excel, which lets you try a few options. (It's with displaying the equation and $R^2$, and try to get a large $R^2$, but don't set the degree to high with a polynomial fit or it's liable to be spurious.)